# active miller clamp and desaturation detection in mosfet drivers?

Tags: power, mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, igbt

Newer mosfet/IGBT gate drivers like [2ED020I12FA](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqzMGXtdXZAhWlDMAKHaq6BggQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infineon.com%2Fdgdl%2FInfineon-2ED020I12FA-DS-v03_01-EN.pdf%3FfileId%3Ddb3a30432e779412012e7b87d2b23878&usg=AOvVaw0fqCxHKZlWh8UHLcSlHRZK) and [TD352](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/td352.pdf) have features called : Active miller clamp and desaturation detection . However the example circuits are shown with IGBTs only.

**So my Questions are :**

1- Does Active Miller Clamp function work and have any significance when driving a Power Mosfet ?

2- Does The desaturation detection function work and have any significance when driving a Power Mosfet ?

Answer (score 2):

(1) I don't see any difference between an Active Miller Clamp, and a decent low driver that can sink current when it's supposed to be driving low. However, specifying what it does suggests that they've thought carefully about keeping the gate voltage low in those circumstances.

(2) The desaturation function should be every bit as useful for a FET as for an IGBT. Under excessive current, it will turn the device off. However, the fact that a FET is ohmic while an IGBT looks like a BJT means that you might want to carefully review the threshhold voltage for the discrimination it will give you between normal, slightly excessive, and grossly excessive currents.

Comment: regarding (2) : that was my main consideration , if Rds is so low say (1mohm) so it would take 1000A , to reach 1v at Vds , which is close to 1v Vce at 50A for example .. i donot know how they solve it or tune it.

Comment: @ElectronS As far as I can tell from the DS, the desat threshold is 9v, and not programmable. If the device is chunky enough, then desat is never an issue. You could always add another mohm or two!